# TableView edit mode doesn't animate cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have implemented a `UITableViewController` which has a custom `UITableViewCell`.

In that `tableView` I have an `Edit` button, which allows me to delete some rows, however when I try to do it the cells don't animate to the right side as usual and I've no idea why this is happening.

Here's an image of what I'm referring to:

[image: img]

When I tap the `Edit` button, the following function is called:

```
@objc func showEditing() {
    tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    rightButton.title = (tableView.isEditing) ? "Done" : "Edit"
}
```

Do you know what may be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you did not set up your constraints correctly...

Comment: Where? In the cell? Everything is like a default UITableView with the exception of having a custom cell.

Comment: Did you set up constraints in your custom cell?

Comment: yes , I have some custom labels there. Do I need to update the constraints in the edit mode? I thought it was the whole cell that would animate to the right side and  not its content

Comment: Actually it is the content... but if you set up constraints correctly everything animates automatically. Where do you set up your custom cell? In interface builder? Or in code?

Comment: I've my labels anchored to the cell's left anchor with some custom width. I'll try out some different constraints there and I'll feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has a `contentView` property where all the content should be. That view is resized in situations like this one, or when you show the reorder indicators.

It seems to me like you constrained your labels to the cell, if you use the `contentView` instead of the cell, your labels should adjust properly when the delete and reorder images are shown.

Comment: ohh.. this I didn't knew. Let me try out as you've said and I'll feedback in a moment

Comment: Solved! Thank you. Just swapped my anchoring from the cell's bounds to the `contentView's bounds` and it animates as expected now.

Comment: Happy to help!.